# Python Pandas - erro na leitura do csv - coluna contém delimitador

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tenho um arquivo csv com campos delimitados por ';'.

Dois campos desse arquivo apresentam conteúdo texto com ';', não sendo o delimitador.

Isso impede a leitura do arquivo.
Como tratar esse problema?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('arquivo.csv', delimiter=';', low_memory=False)
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 107, saw 2
```

No registro 107, o campo "Observações" tem um texto com ';'

O pandas trata esse ';' como delimitador, gerando o erro e interrompendo a leitura do arquivo.

Comment: Pode dar exemplos de linhas desse csv? Se o campo problemático estiver entre limitadores (aspas por exemplo), você pode usar o parâmetro [`quotechar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Desculpe a demora. O campo não está entre aspas, resolvi usando os parâmetros warn_bad_lines=False e error_bad_lines=False. Obrigado

Comment: @CláudioMás por favor coloque a resposta ou aceite a pergunta para fecha-lá. Grato

Comment: @guardian, coloquei a resposta no meu comentário anterior. De qualquer maneira, como faço para fechar uma pergunta?